# How can I make flex box include position values when calculating flex item width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Problem I am facing is that I want my Cards container to expand until the end of screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6vp0.png

*Notice the white space at the end. It is due to position:relative; right:16px;*

How can I tell my flex box container to include right attribute that I have used while shrinking the container to fit the screen.

I know there must be some javascript hack around this. However I was hoping for an easier solution. If it is even possible.

Here is my entire code:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.CardHead {
    display: flex;
    width: 304px;
    height: 304px;
    font-size: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color:black;
}
.Card {
    position: relative;
    width: 304px;
    height: 304px;   
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.Cards {
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 16px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.Carousel {
     display: flex; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>React App</title>

</head>
  <body>
        <div class="Carousel">
            <div class="CardHead"></div>
            <div class="Cards">
                <div class="Card" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
                <div class="Card" style="background-color: green;"></div>
                <div class="Card" style="background-color: purple;"></div>
                <div class="Card" style="background-color: orange;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Apologies if my question or code isn't clear.

Comment: margin-right instead of right?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks alot. It worked. Now I feel dumb though. (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `right` with `margin-right`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.CardHead {
  display: flex;
  width: 304px;
  height: 304px;
  font-size: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}

.Card {
  position: relative;
  width: 304px;
  height: 304px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.Cards {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.Carousel {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="Carousel">
  <div class="CardHead"></div>
  <div class="Cards">
    <div class="Card" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
    <div class="Card" style="background-color: green;"></div>
    <div class="Card" style="background-color: purple;"></div>
    <div class="Card" style="background-color: orange;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```